# Understanding the Role and Implementation of VMID in RISC-V Hypervisor hgatp during Guest OS Switching

Tags: riscv, hypervisor

I'm currently working on implementing a RISC-V hypervisor and have a question regarding hgatp during guest OS switches.

When HSXLEN=64, VMID is located in bits 44 to 57 of hgatp. Although I've consulted "The RISC-V Instruction Set Manual Volume II: Privileged Architecture Ver. 20211203," there is no information about the role of VMID. If VMID is indeed used for distinguishing guest OS instances, it's unclear how it is utilized afterward. The Privileged Architecture only explains its use during SFENCE instructions from within the guest OS. Are there any other applications for VMID?

Furthermore, when the hypervisor switches the guest OS, does hgatp need to be manually switched by software each time? Is there no mechanism in RISC-V hardware where changing the value of VMID in hgatp automatically switches the value of PPN inside hgatp?

Comment: Read this https://developer.arm.com/documentation/102142/0100/Stage-2-translation. RISCV VMID and ASID are similar to ARM. Basically both are used to tag TLB entries. So that TLB entries of different VMs can co-exist without the need of flushing TLBs every time a new VM is scheduled. TLB flush is a costly operation.

Comment: Regarding your other question, no the hgatp can't do this. It doesn't have any hidden storage to store PPN for different VMIDs. Also think about how it will work the first time. Architecture will have to come up with a way to store PPN for VMIDs first which makes things too odd and complex. Instead we just have a single hgatp, just change the pagetables when a VM is switched. Simple.